# Monitor with low screen temperature

Tags: monitors, heat-sink

I'm using an HP ZR30w 30" monitor, which is great to arrange things on the screen, but also gets a very high screen temperature (basically you almost can't touch it). Is there any kind of technology that provides similar screen size and resolution, but operating at lower temperatures?

Here's a [review](https://www.solidsmack.com/3d-cad-technology/hp-zr30w-lcd-monitor-hands-on-review/) where a user claims the same point.

Comment: Your monitor is definitely an odd one out. Most monitors (and computer products in general) on the market should not get hot enough to touch. Also note that the temperature you feel and the actual heat of the components are not always the same. For example, a laptop with a very thermally conductive case will feel hotter to the touch, but actually be quite cool in the core's perspective because the case is efficient at moving heat away from the core.